# File Path from @url.action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this file fontroller on my project:

```
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    public FileResult Index(string path="", string filename="")
    {
        path = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\\Users\\ikerib\\Pictures");
        filename = "header-vietnam.jpg";
        string dirPath = Path.Combine(path, filename);

        return File(dirPath, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);

    }
}
```

It returns a file from any given path such "C:\Files\Filename.jpg", it´s purpouse is to serve files (images) from outside web root, and it works great.

Previously, I have a list of a directory listing all available files like this (Controller):

```
public ActionResult DocumentoLista(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Documento doc = db.Documentos.Find(id);
            if (doc == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            string dirPath = Path.GetFullPath(doc.path);
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
            foreach (string fInfo in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".png") 
                                || s.EndsWith(".jpg")  
                                || s.EndsWith(".pdf")
                             ).Select(Path.GetFileName)
                     )
            {
                files.Add(fInfo);
            }
            ViewBag.MyList = files;
            return View(doc);
        }
```

(view)

```
<ul id="filelist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MyList)
    {        
        <li class="ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child">
            <a href="@Url.Action("showdocument", "Frontend", new { id=1, FileName=@item})" class=" ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">
                <img src=">@Url.Action("Index", "Files", new { path = Model.path, filename = item })">
                <h2>@item</h2>
                <p>@Url.Action("Index", "Files", new { path = Model.path, filename=item })</p>
                <p>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Files", new { path = Model.path, filename = item })</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

The problem is that in the view the file path is written like this:

```
/Files?path=C%3A%5CUsers%5Cikerib%5CPictures&filename=header-vietnam.jpg
```

How could I write my view to send the path properly to my FilesController?

thx!

Comment: It's a really bad idea to allow a web application to access any file outside it's root folder. And it won't work in production environment "out of the box" as it's working in Visual Studio...

Comment: They need to specify a server file path (network drive) where image files will be stored, and I need to serve them on clients browsers ( thew could not have same mapped drives). It´s for my enterprise use only. You know another way to do that?

Comment: I would store the images in a folder under the root web folder, thus avoiding to access a path outside it.
Or maybe you just need to setup an FTP service on the desired folder instead of creating an application for this..

Comment: The images are now stored in a server folder and thew need to be there. They don´t want to upload anything, they just want to serve this files to browser. It´s mandatory. Theese images are created by users and stored on a mapped network drive.